# how do i randomize a string?

Tags: php, string, random

i'm sure this is an easy one, but what would be the best way to randomize text from a string? something like:

```
$content = "{hey|hi|hello there}! {i am|i'm} {good|great}!";
```

how can i make the output like this:

> hey! i'm good!
>       hello there! i am great!
>       etc..

Comment: just an example. it's actually for randomizing articles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try something like:

```
$content = "{hey|hi|hello there}! {i am|i'm} {good|great}!";

$randomOutput = preg_replace('/(\{.*?\})/s', function($matches) {
    $possibilities = (array) explode('|', trim($matches[0], '{}'));

    return $possibilities[array_rand($possibilities)];
}, $content);
```

---

Version for PHP <5.3

```
function randomOutputCallback($matches) {
    $possibilities = (array) explode('|', trim($matches[0], '{}'));

    return $possibilities[array_rand($possibilities)];
}

$content = "{hey|hi|hello there}! {i am|i'm} {good|great}!";

$randomOutput = preg_replace('/(\{.*?\})/s', 'randomOutputCallback', $content);
```

Comment: thanks for that i was trying it on 5.1.6. @crozin maybe a solution similar for older php?

Comment: @john: I've added equivalent for older versions of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an array:

```
$greeting = array("hey","hi","hello there");
$suffix = array("good","great");

$randGreeting = $greeting[rand(0, sizeof($greeting))];
$randSuffix   = $suffix[rand(0,(sizeof($suffix)))];

echo "$randGreeting, I'm $randSuffix!";
```

Of course, you could also write the last line as:

```
echo $randomGreeting . ", I'm " . $randSuffix . "!";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would arrange the elements in an array... Something like [This Live Demo](http://codepad.org/aQnw0tcI).

```
<?php

$responseText = array(
    array("hey","hi","hello there"),
    "! ",
    array("i am", "i'm"),
    " ",
    array("good", "great"),
    "! "
);

echo randomResponse($responseText);

function randomResponse($array){
    $result='';
    foreach ($array as $item){
        if (is_array($item))
            $result.= $item[rand(0, count($item)-1)];
        else
            $result.= $item;
    }
    return ($result);
}
?>
```